# Proving unitary similarity between two Hermitian operators with the same eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quantum-computation

I've been working on a quantum computation problem set at Uni and came across the following problem. I managed to arrive at a proof, but I don't know if I have solved it to its fullest generality.

Consider two Hermitian operators $A$ and $B$ that have the same eigenvalues. Show that they are related by a unitary similarity transformation, $B=UAU^{\dagger}$ with $U^\dagger=U^{-1}$.

**My attempt at a proof:**

We first write the eigenvalue and eigenvector relations for the operators,

$$
A|a_i\rangle=\lambda_i|a_i\rangle, \\
B|b_i\rangle=\lambda_i|b_i\rangle.
$$

Now we define the operator $U=\sum_{i} |b_i\rangle\langle a_i|$ (A basis change).

We write the spectral decompositions of $A$ and $B$ (This is the step that makes me uncomfortable):

$$
A=\sum_i \lambda_i|a_i\rangle\langle a_i|,\\
B=\sum_i \lambda_i|b_j\rangle\langle b_i|.
$$

Applying $U$ to the operators on one side each gives us the relations

$$
UA=\sum_i \lambda_i|b_i\rangle\langle a_i|,\\
BU=\sum_i \lambda_i|b_i\rangle\langle a_i|.
$$

Or, put simply $UA=BU$, with (very easy to check by applying completeness relations, another step that makes me uncomfortable) $U^\dagger=U^{-1}$. **QED?**

Okay, the thing about those two uncomfortable steps is that they have to rely on the validity of the spectral theorem. Reading up on Wikipedia, the conditions for it to hold are extremely restrictive, and that's why I got concerned with the generality of my proof. What other ways are there to show this identity?

Comment: You are assuming that both operators have purely discrete spectrum? That need not be the case, of course...

Comment: @paul garrett Not necessarily. The sum over $i$ could easily be replaced by an integral over some other parameter $x$.

Comment: So you'd be happy enough having an "isomorphism" of spectral projectors? Maybe for separable Hilbert spaces this could work, at least, but having continuous spectrum certainly complicates the assertion and argument. E.g., what _would_ be an acceptable (positive, precise) assertion for you in case there's not a discrete spectrum. Not immediately clear to me...

Comment: @paul garret Honestly, the assumptions I’m making aren’t even clear to myself. Everything about the problem is given on the second paragraph, and underlying assumptions are manifested only in my “proof”.

Comment: looks ok. The spectral decomposition is an important fact  being used.

Comment: If the dimensions of the eigenspaces for a given eigenvalue are not the same, then you cannot have unitary equivalence.